# Unable to see version of socket.io even though files suggest successful installation

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

After installing socket.io using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990494/how-to-install-node-js-npm-socket-io-and-use-them), we tried to confirm the version as explained by [How to see socket.io version on node.js npm server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655180/how-to-see-socket-io-version-on-node-js-npm-server).

Yet when we run the version command, we get `Undefined` back.

```
[root@mongo wok]# node
> require("socket.io").version
undefined
>
```

Yet exploring the directory, it seems installed:

```
[root@mongo wok]# cd node_modules/
[root@mongo node_modules]# ls
socket.io
[root@mongo node_modules]# cd socket.io/
[root@mongo socket.io]# ls
History.md  index.js  lib  LICENSE  Makefile  node_modules  package.json  Readme.md
[root@mongo socket.io]# ls -al
total 68
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Aug 15 01:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Aug 15 01:50 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15740 Jul 14 17:36 History.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    36 Jul  8 09:29 index.js
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug 15 01:50 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1096 May 25 14:29 LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   235 May 25 14:29 Makefile
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root  4096 Aug 15 01:50 node_modules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    33 May 25 14:29 .npmignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1932 Aug 15 01:50 package.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10380 Jul  8 09:29 Readme.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   197 Jul  8 09:29 .travis.yml
[root@mongo socket.io]# cat package.json 
{
  "name": "socket.io",
  "version": "1.3.6",
  "description": "node.js realtime framework server",
  "keywords": [
    "realtime",
    "framework",
    "websocket",
    "tcp",
    "events",
    "socket",
    "io"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/Automattic/socket.io.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --reporter dot --slow 200ms --bail"
  },
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this ( you used very old command)

```
require('socket.io/package').version
```

Comment: There it is; thanks! So if we see the version, it means socket.io is successfully installed? One thing that's still confusing: if all we need to do is use socket.io to manage real-time messages for a Rails app, do we still need to enable the HTTP server in node server? And if we don't, how does the socket.io.js file get served to the browser?